# In Core Data Is there any built-in mechanism to limit instances of a particular entity to a maximum number?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-data

In Core Data Is there any built-in mechanism to limit instances of a particular entity to a maximum number ? For example I have an entity "Student" and I want to limit to 30 students at all cases. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Core Data doesn't include anything that would enforce this limit. If you want an upper limit on instances, you'll have to enforce it yourself.